# Prevent entire RecyclerView from refreshing, add only new item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have nested listeners for to retrieve data: First I retrieve data from the data database, and then, I get a list of users that has this data, and save a list of present users inside an ArrayList, which will be the dataset for the RecyclerView. Then, I need to get some info regarding these users from the users database (their image id), so I do another call to the user database from within the first onDataChange call (since it's async, I need to nest them). But then when I update the ArrayList with new items, or every time there is a change in the database, the RecyclerView sort of "Refreshes". This is the code:

**I think the cause is the fact that I call new adapter every time that `onDataChange` is called. So how to check if the adapter was previously set, and if it was set, then don't set it again?

```
DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dataReference = rootReference.child("data");
ValueEventListener dataListener= new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            final ArrayList<String> foundUsers = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String userId= dSnapshot.getKey();
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {    
                    if (userIsFound()){
                        foundUsers.add(userId);
                    }
                }
            }

            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            // use a linear layout manager
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            myDataset = new ArrayList<User>();
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);                
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


            DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference imageIdRef= rootRef.child("users");
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String currentUserId = ds.getKey();
                        if (foundUsers.contains(currentUserId )) {
                            if (ds.child("imageUrl").getValue() != null) {
                                String imageUrl = ds.child("imageUrl").getValue().toString();
                                myDataset.add(new User(currentUserId, imageUrl));
                            }
                        }
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                           

                    }
                    foundUsers.clear();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            imageIdRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener);

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };

    dataReference.addValueEventListener(dataListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `equals` method at your `User` class so the `contains` will work properly :

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        if( obj instanceof User){
            User = (User) obj;
            return this.getCurrentUserId().equals(obj.getCurrentUserId());
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and use :

```
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(myDataset.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? Isn't it because I call to create new adapter every time that `onDataChange` is called?

Comment: you need to move the adapter initialization out side the firebase logic too

Comment: Ok I moved it out, but now the problem is caused the the `new User` statement- which adds new instance of same user multiple times. How to prevent this? Your code doesn't work

Comment: I think I must use HashMap instead of ArrayList to prevent duplicates, no?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
```

or try below, it will notify last added position

```
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted((myDataset.size())-1);
```

Comment: that's not the problem, I think the problem is that I set new adapter every time there is call to the database